# Run Laravel phpMyAdmin via php artisan serve

Tags: laravel, phpmyadmin, laravel-artisan, artisan-serve

I have a Laravel project running with `php artisan serve` (no Apache or Nginx) on:

```
http://localhost:8000/
```

I have then ran this successfully

```
composer require phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
```

My question is, what additions to Laravel's routing etc. must I do to run the following?

```
http://localhost:8000/phpmyadmin
```

Comment: Where did you found that you can install phpmyadmin in laravel with `composer require phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin`, in the official docs or elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Though I haven't found a specific way to have

```
http://localhost:8000/phpmyadmin
```

working through Laravel as part of `php artisan serve`, there is a simple solution that works just fine using PHP's native server instead, assuming you have `mysql` installed as localhost:

```
composer create-project phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
cd phpmyadmin
ls -la #files look like classic phpMyAdmin, note however `vendor` folder in place along with package.json
php -S http://localhost:7000    #and you should be able to see and log in!
```

This does everything I need it to do.  If you want to install phpMyAdmin through an actual webserver like Apache that runs always, you're better off doing something like `apt-get [or yum] install phpmyadmin`  and then you'll have a directory override from Apache running:

```
http://www.mylaravelapp.com/phpmyadmin
```